# validating an email input in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, input

Hello I have made a function in order to check for the format the user has enter. However I do not know how to print a message if the format is wrong.

```
function emailIsValid (emailInput) {
    //var check =  /\S+@\S+\.\S/.test(emailInput);
    var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    if( re.test(String(emailInput).toLowerCase()))
    {
        return true;
    }
}


  export default function Contact() {

  const [nameInput, setName] = React.useState("");
  const [emailInput, setEmail] = React.useState("");
  const [messageInput, setMessageInput] = React.useState("");
  var emailCheck = emailIsValid(emailInput);

  const enables = messageInput.length > 0 && emailInput.length > 0 && nameInput.length > 0 && emailCheck;

  return (

    <div className="App">

     <div className="header">
            <div className="logo">
              Chavy
            </div>

     <div className="menu">

     <Link className="link" activeonlywhenexact="true" to="/">
        <span className="title" style={{cursor:"pointer"}}>Home</span>
          <span className="bar"></span>
        </Link>
        <Link className="link" to="/workSection">
        <span className="title" style={{cursor:"pointer"}}>Work</span>
          <span className="bar"></span>
        </Link>
        <Link className="link" to="/contact">
        <span className="title" style={{cursor:"pointer"}}>Contact</span>
          <span className="bar"></span>
        </Link>
       </div>

    </div>
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="column">
          <img src={logo} style={{height:"500px", width:"600px"}} alt="logo"/>
         </div>
         <div className="row">
         <div className="column column-10"><hr className="style-four"></hr></div>

        <p style={{margin:"30px"}}>
        ---
        </p>
        <label htmlFor="fname" style={{fontSize:"20px", fontWeight:"200"}}>Full Name:</label>
        <br />
        <input type="text" id="firstname" placeholder="Your name:"
            value={nameInput}
            name="name"
            onChange={event => {
              const value = event.target.value;
               setName(value);
            }}
            required
        />

     <br />
     <div style={{margin:"30px"}}>
    <label htmlFor="lname" style={{fontSize:"20px", fontWeight:"200"}}>Email:</label>
        <br />
    <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Your email:"
        value={emailInput}
        name="email"
        onChange={event => {
            const value = event.target.value;
            setEmail(value);
        }}
        required
        />
    <br />
    </div>
    <div style={{margin:"30px"}}>
    <label htmlFor="textarea" style={{fontSize:"20px", fontWeight:"200"}}>Message:</label>
     <br />
    <textarea id="message" placeholder="Type your message here:"
    value={messageInput}
    onChange={event => {
       const value = event.target.value;
       setMessageInput(value);
    }}
    name="message"
    required
    />
   <br />
   <Link to="/contactAfter">
   <button
    disabled={!enables}
    onClick={() =>
    sendMessage(messageInput,emailInput,nameInput)
    }
    className="myButton"
    name = "messageInput"
   >Send Message</button></Link>
   </div>
         </div>
        </div>
```

whenever the user is done writing his email, I want to not let him send a message if the email has a wrong format. This info is being sent to a db in firebase.

Comment: I guess what you should do is make the submit button disabled until all fields are valid, if any field is invalid you should probably tell the user that the field is invalid. For instance "Enter a valid email address"

Answer (score 1):

You may try this

Insert this

```
{!emailCheck && <div className="red">Invalid email address</div>}
```

right after

```html
    <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Your email:"
        value={emailInput}
        name="email"
        onChange={event => {
            const value = event.target.value;
            setEmail(value);
        }}
        required
        />
```

You may refer to the link https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-email-error